# Find closest pairs of point-sets in three-dimensions

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I have a large number of point-sets.

Each set is a collection of `P` points in three dimensions. All sets have the same `P`. You can think of the points as representing the vertices of a polyhedron that has been rotated many different ways. Since the polyhedron has a large number of symmetries, it is difficult to find the closest neighbouring orientation with reference to its rotation alone.

For a given set point, I want to find the nearest neighbouring point-set.

My current algorithm is as follows:

I throw all of the points into a kd-tree. For a given point-set, I use the kd-tree to find the `X` nearest neighbours to each point. I then determine which point-sets, if any, are represented in each neighbour-group. Since two nearby point-sets must have their points among the nearest neighbors of each other, this is a quickish way to find candidates.

At the moment, I am defining the between two point-sets like so: Of the possible pairings of points between a set A and B, I choose the one that minimizes the sum of the Euclidean distances between the paired points.

My question is whether there is a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Are the points in any kind of order?  For example, does the first point in set A correspond to the first point in set B if you rotated the coordinates?

Comment: @stark: Alas, no, symmetries mean that different combinations of rotations can lead to similar placements. However, I think the kNN look-up will implicitly which pairs to use so that all pairings need not be checked between two point sets.

Comment: Are there cases where a small rotation makes points close, but a larger rotation makes the points closer?

Comment: @stark: I think that very well may be the case.